# Sending your potential advisors your preprint that you have not posted on arXiv

Tags: advisor, application, postdocs, preprint

I have written up a preprint that I have not posted on arXiv yet, as I keep modifying it. It is advisable to send that preprint to my potential postdoctoral advisors before I have posted it on arXiv, so that they may have a better idea of my research? One may imagine this to be a high-trust environment, in which these advisors will not steal my work.

Comment: If it's not on arxiv, is it a preprint? Isn't that just a manuscript?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there should be no problem with this. People in general are honest as well as helpful. Presumably you are applying to people with a solid reputation and you have already explored that.

Don't send out a scattershot appeal, however, using such a pre-pre-print or not.

I would only send such things in a second email after you already gain some positive feedback from the first one in which you state that you have a work in progress that you can share with them confidentially. You can mention that it is soon to be posted.

In general, don't flood a potential supervisor with information in a first mail unless you are applying for an advertised position that gives some indication of what is required.